# Android buttons in relative view - Have buttons fill available width

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout

I have a 9 buttons labeled 1 through 9 in a 3 by 3 Calculator like configuration. These are all contained in a relative view. I would like to have the buttons grow wider than they need to be and fill the available width of the relative view. The relative view is set to fill parent. I would also like to leave at least a small gap between the buttons so that they are not touching. What is the best way to approach this?

```html
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn0"
        android:id="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnStart"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click"
        android:tag="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn1"
        android:id="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:tag="1"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn2"
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:tag="2"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnNegative"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNegative"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNegative" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn3"
        android:id="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:tag="3"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn4"
        android:id="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:tag="4"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn5"
        android:id="@+id/btn5"
        android:tag="5"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn6"
        android:id="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn3"
        android:tag="6"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn7"
        android:id="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btn4"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:tag="7"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn8"
        android:id="@+id/btn8"
        android:tag="8"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn7"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn9"
        android:id="@+id/btn9"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn8"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn6"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn6"
        android:tag="9"
        android:onClick="btnNumber_Click" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btnEnter"
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btn0"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btn3"
        android:onClick="btnEnter_Click"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btn3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btn3"
        android:singleLine="false" />
```

Thanks,

David

Comment: If you want them to fill the screen and grow equally in width, the best answer is a LinearLayout for each row, so you can give them equal weights.  Relative layouts don't have a matching concept.

Comment: Thanks Gabe. So I just place 1 Linear Layout for each row of buttons inside the Relative layout? Then since I have 3 columns, I would assign a weight of 33% to each column?

Comment: Yes.  The other part of the trick is that you need to give those buttons a layout_width of 0dp, combined with a weight.  This tells the system to size them based on the weights, filling all available room in the parent.  The row's linear layout should be set to match_parent width.

Comment: Use padding for the space between the buttons.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your responses. Unfortunately, I couldn't mark them all as the Answer, but they were all very helpful and I got it to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you layout should be,

And also set `margin` to all buttons to have some space between them.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <Button
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks Apuvra, this is essentially what I implemented.